# Jtree not shown on JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display a JTree on a JScrollPane in a JFrame. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2;

public class TreeView {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTree tree;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

    public TreeView() {

    }

    private void show() {
        frame = new JFrame("TreeView");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        addComponents();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponents() {
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        JButton button = new JButton("Select File");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ae) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter xmlfilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "xml files (*.xml)", "xml");
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(xmlfilter);
                int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        showAsTree(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        tree = new JTree(root);
                        JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);

                        frame.add(treeView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    }

    private void showAsTree(final String file)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxparser = factory.newSAXParser();
        saxparser.parse(file, new MyContentHandler());

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
                treeView.show();
            }

        });
    }

    private class MyContentHandler extends DefaultHandler2 {


        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

            root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

            DefaultMutableTreeNode abc = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
                    "abc");
            DefaultMutableTreeNode de = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
                    "de");


            root.add(abc);
            root.add(de);

        }

    }
}
```

When I tried adding text to a `JTextPane` inside the `JScrollPane`, everything worked fine. And when I try to display the tree in the `show()` method or in the `addComponents()` method before I add the button, it is also displayed.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the frame and/or it's `contentPane`. Personally, I create and the `JTree` to the frame before you made it visible and then simply update it's `TreeModel` when you needed to

Answer (score 2):

Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the frame and/or it's `contentPane`.

```
showAsTree(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
tree = new JTree(root);
JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);

frame.add(treeView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

Personally, I create and add the `JTree` to the frame before you made it visible and then simply update it's `TreeModel` when you needed to

Comment: but why is this necessary? When I place the code into the show() method, I dont need to call repaint or anything...

Comment: Because that's how the API works.  In your `show` method you are calling `setSize` and `setVisible` which will in invalidating and repainting the container.  Swing is lazy when it comes to updating the UI, because it would be inefficient to update the UI on every little change you make, as a apposed to doing one big update when you're ready